# Trying to develop a simple web using the Google Speech API, don't know where to start

Tags: google-app-engine, speech-to-text

I am trying to use the Google Speech API to transcribe audio captured from a semi-embedded device. The device supports python scripts, but does not seem to offer any way to allow imports.

I have managed to get the speech API sample program working on my computer, but since I cannot import the necessary modules, I see myself forced to develop a web application that accepts an audio file and returns the transcript.

I am completely new at web development, and so far I have concluded that I'm going to need to use Google App Engine, but beyond that I'm completely lost.

I have identified the following steps, and if someone could point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated:

1. Allow uploading of a flac file to a certain URL.
2. Upload the flac file to the google speech API and receive the transcription (I'm fairly certain I could manage this myself).
3. Return the transcription to the device somehow.

I'm not asking for finished code or anything, but it would be nice if somebody could tell me at the very least if what I want to do is possible with the google app engine, or if I need to look for something else.

Comment: yes possible from appengine. to make the question valid, show us attempts and issues.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is absolutely possible with Google App Engine. Take a look at the [App Engine Python tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tutorials) to get started with the environment etc., but it sounds like what you want will involve an API that accepts a POST with binary data in the body (the FLAC) and then passes that to the Speech API (try the [GRPC samples](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/grpc)).

Good luck! :)